# Params in change of variables in ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\frac{dx}{dt} = x(a-bx)$ be a ODE with $a, b > 0$. Considering the change of variables $s = \alpha t$ and $y = \beta x$. I need to find $\alpha, \beta$ that transforms the equation into $\frac{dy}{ds} = y(1-y)$.

Appling the chain rule, I obtain

$$
\frac{dy}{ds} = \frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{ds}{dt}} = \frac{\beta}{\alpha} \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{\beta}{\alpha} x (a-bx)
$$

And replacing $y = \beta x$ and simplifing I get
$$
1 - \beta x = \frac{\beta}{\alpha}x(a-bx)
$$

How can i continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started from your last line:
$$\frac{dy}{ds}= \frac{\beta}{\alpha} x (a-bx)$$
$$\frac{dy}{ds} = \frac{a}{\alpha} y (1-\dfrac b {a\beta }y)$$
$$\implies \alpha =a$$
$$\dfrac b{a\beta}=1\implies \beta =\dfrac ba$$